Как настроить Прокси для мобильной сети на Goofle Pixel 5a 5g?
Для Wi-FI там всё понятно, но для мобильной сети не совсем. Такой же странички с расширенными настройками нет.
Если я пытаюсь вводить данные в меню "Точки доступа" в настройках мобильной сети, то пропадает подключение к интернету. Если кто знает или сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать

какой-нибудь там 4pda, вероятно, более подходит для подобных вопросов.

Здесь нет никакой проблемы, если вводить данные в Proxy APN, про которые оператор сотовой связи ничего не знает, естественно интернет будет недоступен. Не описана цель использования proxy.

@Oopss для обхода блокировок. Подскажите пожалуйста, куда тогда вводить данные сервера

Можно устнавить на смартфон и домашний комп zerotier.com , дома настроить прокси или разрешить транзитный трафик (например через vpn), смартфон получит доступ к "домашнему" интернету.
